# Lazy Hydrate + Code Splitting on NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I know how to do Lazy Hydration and I know how to do Code Splitting, but how can I make the splitted chunck download only when the component is hydrating?

My code looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import ReactLazyHydrate from 'react-lazy-hydration';

const MyComponent = dynamic(() => import('components/my-component').then((mod) => mod.MyComponent));

export const PageComponent = () => {
  return (
    ...
    <ReactLazyHydrate whenVisible>
      <MyComponent/>
    </ReactLazyHydrate>
    ...
  );
};
```

`MyComponent` is rendered below the fold, which means that it is only gonna hydrate when the user scrolls. The problem is that the JS chunck for `MyComponent` will be downloaded right away when the page loads.

I was able to hack it by using the dynamic import only on client but this makes the component disappear for a second when it hydrates, because the html rendered on server will not be used by react. It will recreate the DOM element and it will be empty until the JS chunck loads.
When the element disappear for a sec it increases the page CLS and that's the main reason why I can not use this hack.
Here is the code for this hack

```
const MyComponent = typeof window === 'undefined'
    ? require('components/my-component').MyComponent
    : dynamic(() => import('components/my-component').then((mod) => mod.MyComponent));
```

Note that I want to render the component's HTML on the server render. That't why I don't want to Lazy Load it. I want to Lazy Hydrate so I can have the component's HTML rendered on server but only download
and execute it's JS when it is visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update:

In document:

```
// stops preloading of code-split chunks
class LazyHead extends Head {
  getDynamicChunks(files) {
    const dynamicScripts = super.getDynamicChunks(files);
    try {
      // get chunk manifest from loadable
      const loadableManifest = __non_webpack_require__(
        '../../react-loadable-manifest.json',
      );
      // search and filter modules based on marker ID
      const chunksToExclude = Object.values(loadableManifest).filter(
        manifestModule => manifestModule?.id?.startsWith?.('lazy') || false,
      );
      const excludeMap = chunksToExclude?.reduce?.((acc, chunks) => {
        if (chunks.files) {
          acc.push(...chunks.files);
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);
      const filteredChunks = dynamicScripts?.filter?.(
        script => !excludeMap?.includes(script?.key),
      );

      return filteredChunks;
    } catch (e) {
      // if it fails, return the dynamic scripts that were originally sent in
      return dynamicScripts;
    }
  }
}

const backupScript = NextScript.getInlineScriptSource;
NextScript.getInlineScriptSource = (props) => {
  // dont let next load all dynamic IDS, let webpack manage it
  if (props?.__NEXT_DATA__?.dynamicIds) {
    const filteredDynamicModuleIds = props?.__NEXT_DATA__?.dynamicIds?.filter?.(
      moduleID => !moduleID?.startsWith?.('lazy'),
    );
    if (filteredDynamicModuleIds) {
      // mutate dynamicIds from next data
      props.__NEXT_DATA__.dynamicIds = filteredDynamicModuleIds;
    }
  }
  return backupScript(props);
};
```

in next config

```
const mapModuleIds = fn => (compiler) => {
  const { context } = compiler.options;

  compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('ChangeModuleIdsPlugin', (compilation) => {
    compilation.hooks.beforeModuleIds.tap('ChangeModuleIdsPlugin', (modules) => {
      const { chunkGraph } = compilation;
      for (const module of modules) {
        if (module.libIdent) {
          const origId = module.libIdent({ context });
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          if (!origId) continue;
          const namedModuleId = fn(origId, module);
          if (namedModuleId) {
              chunkGraph.setModuleId(module, namedModuleId);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
};

const withNamedLazyChunks = (nextConfig = {}) => Object.assign({}, nextConfig, {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      mapModuleIds((id, module) => {
        if (
          id.includes('/global-brand-statement.js')
          || id.includes('signposting/signposting.js')
          || id.includes('reviews-container/index.js')
          || id.includes('why-we-made-this/why-we-made-this.js')
        ) {
          return `lazy-${module.debugId}`;
        }
        return false;
      }),
    );

    if (typeof nextConfig.webpack === 'function') {
      return nextConfig.webpack(config, options);
    }

    return config;
  },
});
```

In file, using next/dynamic

```
    <LazyHydrate whenVisible style={null} className="col-xs-12">
      <GlobalBrandStatement data={globalBrandData} />
    </LazyHydrate>
```

Comment: I just wanna share the article that you wrote about this in case someone need more details
https://scriptedalchemy.medium.com/next-js-and-lazy-hydration-keep-the-html-but-drop-the-javascript-846feb2da1f

Comment: @RafaelLebre Do you have any repo implementing the above stuff?
I am getting lot of errors while using the _document.js code. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: I don't have a repo Alak. I tried it and it worked at some point but I didn't save it to a repo. Fell free to DM me on [twitter](https://twitter.com/lebreRafael) for help on debugging

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you’re after, but I use lazy hydration mixed with webpack plugin and custom next head to preserve the html but strip out below the fold dynamic imported scripts. So I only download the JS and hydrate the component just before the user scrolls into view. Regardless of it the component was used during render - I don’t need the runtime unless a user is going to see it.

Currently in production and has reduced initial page load by 50%. No impact to SEO

Get me on twitter @scriptedAlchemy if you need the implementation, I’ve not yet written a post about it - but I can tell you it’s totally possible to achieve this “download as you scroll” design with very little effort.

Comment: Hi Zackary. This answer may point into a certain direction, it doesnt help to actually the answer at all tho. Adding the mentioned code including some explanation could make this a great answer, as it stands it doesnt actually answer the question tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const MyComponent = dynamic(() => import("components/my-component"));

export const PageComponent = () => {
  const [downloadComp, setDownloadComp] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="some-class-name">
        <button onClick={() => setDownloadComp(true)}>
          Download the component
        </button>
        {downloadComp && <MyComponent />}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

The above code will download the  once you hit the button. If you want it to download if your scroll to  position in that case you can use something like `react-intersection-observer` to set the `setDownloadComp`. I don't have experience using `react-lazy-hydration` but I have been using `react-intersection-observer` and nextjs dynamic import to lazy load components that depends on user scroll.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. This would Lazy Load the component and I don't want that. I want to keep the component in the server render and only Lazy Hydrate it. This way I would always have the component rendered in the HTML but the JS for that component would only be downloaded and run when it is visible

Comment: oh, Sorry, I couldn't help. May be someone will have the answer, Or we have to wait for reacts upcoming release. But I believe you can use ```react-intersection-observer``` to mimic this. I'm using this for infinity-scroll. once user reach a certain point I load the next content, not unless user scroll very quickly, they will not notice the loading component.

Comment: yea, maybe next react release will have something to deal with this situation. I'm still looking on react repo for something related and I will post here if I find something

Answer (score 0):

I have made a library to make this thing simple. And you can benefit with:

- Fully HTML page render (Better for SEO)
- Only load JS and Hydrate when needed (Better for PageSpeed)

How to use it

```
import lazyHydrate from 'next-lazy-hydrate';

// Lazy hydrate when scroll into view
const WhyUs = lazyHydrate(() => import('../components/whyus'));

// Lazy hydrate when users hover into the view
const Footer = lazyHydrate(
  () => import('../components/footer', { on: ['hover'] })
);

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <AboveTheFoldComponent />
      {/* ----The Fold---- */}
      <WhyUs />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Read more: https://github.com/thanhlmm/next-lazy-hydrate